# Scala Dynamic class to inner dynamic class

Tags: scala

I am create JSON to scala class.

I want `test.c.a` but error Compilation failed

```
import scala.language.dynamics
import scala.collection.mutable

object Json extends App{

    class dynamicClass extends Dynamic {
        var map = mutable.Map[String, Any]()

        def selectDynamic(key: String) = map(key)        
        def updateDynamic(key: String)(value: Any) {             
            map(key) = value 
        }
        override def toString = map.toString()
    }

    var test = new dynamicClass
    var innerTest = new dynamicClass
    innerTest.a = "zzzz"
    innerTest.b = "asdfsdf"

    test.a = "this a"
    test.b = "this b"
    test.c = new dynamicClass

    println(test.c.a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a `Map` of `Any`, so the compiler doesn't know that `test.c` is an instance of `dynamicClass`, Scala is strongly typed.

You can use type parameters in order to tell `selectDynamic` that your object is an instance of `dynamicClass`. It is not good at all the use of `asInstanceOf`, you can replace it with  pattern matching.

```
import scala.language.dynamics
import scala.collection.mutable
import reflect.runtime.universe._

object Json extends App {

  class dynamicClass extends Dynamic {

    var map = mutable.Map[String, Any]()

    def selectDynamic[A : TypeTag](key: String):A = map(key).asInstanceOf[A]

    def updateDynamic(key: String)(value: Any) {
      map(key) = value
    }
    override def toString = map.toString()
  }

  var test = new dynamicClass
  var innerTest = new dynamicClass
  innerTest.a = "zzzz"
  innerTest.b = "asdfsdf"

  test.a = "this a"
  test.b = "this b"
  test.c = innerTest

  println(test.c[dynamicClass].a)

}
```